# Multi transaction GAS

Tags: gas, gas-price

Let's suppose i have 5 customer. Each customer must give me 1 Ether.

I have 2 solutions:

- I generate a single Ethereum Address and i give the same address to all my customers.
- I do not want to give the same address to all my customers. So i generate 5 Ethereum Adresses.

What i will get:

- First case: I will have a single Ethereum Account with 5 Ethers.
- Second case: I will have 5 Ethereum accounts, with 1 Ethers on each.

Now, let's suppose i want to buy something which cost 5 Ether.

- In first case: I will make a single transaction of 5 Ethers from my single Account
- In the second case: I will make 5 transactions because i need to fetch my 1+1+1+1+1 which are on different accounts.

I think i will pay more GAS in second case because i have 5 transaction instead of 1.

But someone told me it was possible to realize 5 transactions in a single transaction. How can this be possible ? Does this person jokes ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If the wallets are smart contracts then it should be possible to make 5 transfer in a single transaction. If the wallets are EOA it is not possible.

Comment: Yes but if the wallets are smartcontracts, we need 5 lines of code. So more GAS...

Comment: There are other solutions like https://blog.coinbase.com/usdc-payment-processing-in-coinbase-commerce-b1af1c82fb0, but all of them involve smart contracts.

Comment: Okay but what i want to know is if it will cost more gas than a basic single transaction

Comment: For each transaction a minimum is 21k gas is paid, for five you wil pay 105k. For a contract deployment 105k seems low, depends on how good you are writing solidity code. I'd guess for 5 transactions you will not save much. Sorry, but I don't have exact numbers.